# Qt5's QPA can not connect to my display?

Tags: qt, wayland

I am trying to launch the Garuda Boot Manager and get this:

```
qt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to display :0
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, wayland-egl, wayland, wayland-xcomposite-egl, wayland-xcomposite-glx, webgl, xcb.
```

This is strange, as other Qt applications work fine. Is this an issue with how it elevates permissions or something? I can not seem to get this working...

I am on Wayfire which only runs on Wayland with Nouveau drivers for my MacBook's ancient GT 350M. Is this possibly the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what's with Xwayland and xcb about this, but I workaround by setting the QT_QPA_PLATFORM environment variable for the program execution to one of the other ones, the "wayland" one